# как настроить css на jsf

Tags: html, css, jsf

Пытаюсь настроить css стиль для тегов jsf (primefaces). Хочу настроить стиль для тега outputLabel т.е. что бы стиль действовал для всех тегов outputLabel.

css

```
outputLabel{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

html

```
 <p:outputLabel for="someId" value="text" />
```

И такая конструкция не работает. Понимаю, что можно сделать

css

```
.myClass{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

html

```
 <p:outputLabel for="someId" value="text" styleClass="myClass" />
```

И это работает. Но не хочу во всем документе каждому из тегов приписывать styleClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет такого тега в `HTML` - `outputLabel`, это компонент `JSF`, а не `HTML`. Соответственно, браузеры про него ничего не знают, и при обработке `CSS` не знают что с ним делать. Более того: тег `outputLabel` отсутствует на `HTML`-странице (см. в отладчике браузера), поэтому, даже если бы браузер его "*понимал*", то всё равно бы не нашёл. `JSF` при обработке тега `outputLabel` должен генерировать на странице тег `<label>`, и именно к нему следует применять стиль:

```
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

PS. Рекомендую периодически смотреть в отладчике браузера то, что генерирует JSF при обработке страницы - это даст большее понимание спецификаций и фреймворков.